# Conditional compilation of class

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor

Normally, for classes I don't intend to include in production code I have conditional operators such as the usual:

```
#ifdef DEBUG_VERSION
```

This could also be around certain chunks of code that performs additional steps in development mode.

I've just thought (after many years or using the above): What happens if a typo is introduced in the above? It could have great consequences. Pieces of code included (or not included) when the opposite was intended.

So I'm now wondering about alternatives, and thought about creating 2 macro's:

```
INCLUDE_IN_DEBUG_BUILD
END_INCLUDE_IN_DEBUG_BUILD
```

If a typo is ever created in these, an error message is created at compile time, forcing the user to correct it. The first would evaluate to "if (1){" in the debug build and "if (0){" in the production build, so any compiler worth using should optimise those lines out, and even if they don't, at least the code inside will never be called.

Now I'm wondering: Is there something I'm missing here? Why does no-one else use something like this?

Comment: Your current macro allows you to remove functions or classes as well as code.  Your proposed new macros will only be able to remove code (from inside a function).  The former seems more flexible.  Do you only ever need to remove code from functions which exist in debug and production builds?

Comment: This is the kind of thing unit/integration tests are supposed to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: I replaced the header-based approach with a build-system based approach.

You want to be able to disable not just part of the code inside a function, but maybe also in other areas like inside a class or namespace:

```
struct my_struct {
#ifdef DEBUG_VERSION
    std::string trace_prefix;
#endif
};
```

So the real question seems to be: How to prevent typos in your `#ifdef`s? Here's something which does not limit you and which should work well.

Modify your build system to either define `DEBUG_VERSION` or `RELEASE_VERSION`. It should be easy to ensure this. Define those to nothing, e.g. `-DDEBUG_VERSION` or `-DRELEASE_VERSION` for GCC/Clang.

With this, you can protect your code like this:

```
#ifdef DEBUG_VERSION
DEBUG_VERSION
// ...
#endif
```

or

```
#ifndef DEBUG_VERSION
DEBUG_VERSION
// ...
#else
RELEASE_VERSION
// ...
#endif
```

And voila, in the second example above, I already added a small typo: `#ifndef` instead of `#ifdef` - but the compiler would complain now as `DEBUG_VERSION` and `RELEASE_VERSION` are not defined (as in "defined away" by the header) in the corresponding branches.

To make it as safe as possible, you should always have both branches with the two defines, so the first example I gave should be improved to:

```
#ifdef DEBUG_VERSION
DEBUG_VERSION
// ...
#else
RELEASE_VERSION
#endif
```

even if the release branch contains no other code/statements. That way you can catch most errors and I think it is quite descriptive. Since the `DEBUG_VERSION` is replaced with nothing only in the debug branch, all typos will lead to a compile-time error. The same for `RELEASE_VERSION`.

Comment: I'm probably being slow but what extra protection does this offer?  If the OP mis-types `DEBUG_VERSION`, won't they end up with code that is omitted from both production and development builds?  This might cause a dev build to fail but I don't see how it'd cause a production build to bloat.

Comment: @simonc If the OP mistypes `DEBUG_VERSION`, he would end up in the release branch. If he makes it a habbit to always have both branches and put `IN_RELEASE_BRANCH` and `IN_DEBUG_BRANCH` in, any typo will lead to a compile error. I should (will) edit the answer and add that it is most safe when you always have both branches.

Comment: When would a mistype cause this problem.  If you write `#ifdef DEBUG_VERSION_WRONG` you'll end up with code that is disabled in both production and dev builds.  If the typo is in your build command, `/DDEBUG_VERSION_WRONG` will also fail to enable dev functionality.  In neither case does extra functionality make its way into a production build.

Comment: Are you thinking about `#ifdef DEBUG_VERSION /* dev code goes here */ #else /* production code goes here.  We don't run this in dev */ #endif`?  Typos would be problematic here but the pattern - dev builds which don't exercise production code - seems pretty nasty.

Comment: @simonc I assume that the build-system is doing its own checks and not requiring you to manually type "DEBUG_VERSION" every time. That said if the build system sets `DEBUG_VERSION`, only `IN_DEBUG_VERSION` is defined and hence replaced with nothing. If you mistype it, you end up in the release branch which has `IN_RELEASE_BRANCH` in it. Since this is *not* defined by the header in the debug build, it will generate a compile-time error. Concerning your second comment: No, that is not what I'm thinking of.